# How do you have managed a status of contents in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, status

How do you have created a status of blog, micropost and etc?
I simply have created a status which each application entity has a status code of boolean.
False is private, true is public.
It is a multi-user environment in fosuserbundle.

It was created without any problems until now.

However, I wanted to be able to set user, group, and other status set in a multi-user environment.
(like a linux permissions, 744, etc...)

So, I think that it might create a bundle that manages the status.

The comment bundle that I have created is relation each application bundle by the ID of the string.

```
{{ render(controller('MyCommentBundle:Default:embed', {
    'id'     : 'for_example_micropost_' ~ micropost.id, // => relation id
    'name'   : micropost.owner.username,
    'request': app.request
})) }}
```

However, it can not use when viewing list of application contents.
(Because the query occurs in one by one)

For example, either simply relationship by creating a column for each application.

Status Entity

```
blog_id
micropost_id
picture_id
etc...
```

But I think it inconvenient.
It require care of additional column when generated for each new application.
And I feel it is not a smart also.

For example, do so in the list part. Conditions of the string if possible in DQL.

```
public function find_all($owner, $limit, $offset)
{
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT p FROM MyMicropostBundle:Post p
        LEFT JOIN MyStatusBundle s
            With s.relation_id = :prefix + p.id
        WHERE s.code > 744
    ')
    ->setParameter("prefix", 'for_example_micropost_')
    ->setParameter("owner", $owner)
    ->setMaxResults($limit)
    ->setFirstResult($offset);

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

Etc., various I think, but I do not know the best way.

How do you have created a status?
Do you know status bundle already?
Or do you know bundle may be relevant to me.

If there is an optimal way and ideas, please tell me.

---

**StatusBundle process:**
It check a access user first.
It check a status code and groups and owner associated with the contents.
It compare a status code, groups and owner of the content to a access user.

I think it is possible to create (relation) bundle within a single page in my skills.
However, problem is how to relations at such a list display page that query to get the contents of the large number.

For example, I get the data of the last 10 blog posts.
I get the last 10 of public status posts if a access user is not the owner.
It is easy if Post entity has a status.
However, I think how to check a status, groups and owner if a status of a post has been registered in the status entity of other bundle.
I think that how to handle the status bundle while I get the data of the contents of the large number.

Comment: Trying to implement Unix rights in Symfony2 may require a lot of work. Did you took a look at [ACL (Access Control Lists)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html)?

Comment: Although I had the idea that it can be implemented, I think it will go beyond the my skills... I think it will impossible that get a list of limited data by the authority(owner, many groups, guest), if I apply the ACL though. Although it was ideal what if it is possible that summarized as a bundle, it is likely that each application should have separately status and have a check process.